# AppMessage always fails with APP_MSG_SEND_TIMEOUT

Tags: javascript, c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to send a simple message from my Pebble to a JS app, but it always fails with the error code APP_MSG_SEND_TIMEOUT. Sending a message from JS to the device, however, works like a charm. Here's my code:

```
app_message_register_inbox_received(in_received_handler);
app_message_register_inbox_dropped(in_dropped_handler);
app_message_register_outbox_sent(out_sent_handler);
app_message_register_outbox_failed(out_failed_handler);

const uint32_t inbound_size = 512;
const uint32_t outbound_size = 512;
app_message_open(inbound_size, outbound_size);

// some UI things...

DictionaryIterator *iter;
app_message_outbox_begin(&iter);

if(iter == NULL)
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "null iter");

Tuplet value = TupletInteger(0, 42);
dict_write_tuplet(iter, &value);
dict_write_end(iter);
app_message_outbox_send();
```

All of my handlers contain only a few lines of logging code. My JS is:

```
Pebble.addEventListener("ready",
    function(e) {
        console.log("JavaScript app ready and running!");
    Pebble.sendAppMessage({"0": 42, "1": "hello"}, function(e) {
        console.log("success");
        }, function(e) {
        console.log("fail");
    });
    }
);

Pebble.addEventListener("appmessage", function(e) {
    console.log("received message: " + e.payload);
});
```

Finally, my log output is this:

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: {'runhost client uuid' = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}:{'webapp uuid' = 00e9f277-489d-4c97-87ba-22659062bf12}: ++_JS_LIFECYCLE_++:LAUNCHING
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: {'runhost client uuid' = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}:{'webapp uuid' = 00e9f277-489d-4c97-87ba-22659062bf12}: ++_JS_LIFECYCLE_++:LAUNCHING
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: CTwitch__1/pebble-js-app.js:3 JavaScript app ready and running!
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: {'runhost client uuid' = 833ceb3c-9bf6-40e5-a14d-48c401515ca2}:{'webapp uuid' = 00e9f277-489d-4c97-87ba-22659062bf12}: ++_JS_LIFECYCLE_++:READY-RUNNING
[DEBUG] hello_world.c:15: Got message!
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: CTwitch__1/pebble-js-app.js:5 success
[ERROR] hello_world.c:71: Outbox failed!
[ERROR] hello_world.c:72: APP_MSG_SEND_TIMEOUT
```

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Can you post your code on github and share it so we can try? What you are doing looks good.

Comment: Just posted it, it's here: https://github.com/shawnwalton/twitch

Answer (score 1):

I guess you worked out the answer yourself, but omitted to post it here.

It's a timing problem between the watch and the phone.

If you delay sending till later in the app, once everything is loaded and "settled down", it works as per the book.

See my post on the [pebble SDK](http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/18315/send-timeout-when-sending-app-msg-to-pebblekit-js) forum